# RXJS publishLast doesn't publish the last emitted value?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

```
import { Observable, of, Subject, AsyncSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { publishLast, publishBehavior, publishReplay, tap } from 'rxjs/operators'

    const subject = new Subject();
    subject.pipe(
      tap(val => console.log('inside', val)),
      publishLast()
    );

    subject.subscribe(val => console.log('a :', val));

    subject.next('1');
    subject.next('2');
    subject.next('3');

    subject.subscribe(val => console.log('b :', val));
```

**Output**

```
a : 1
a : 2
a : 3
```

I expected `a : 3` and  `b : 3` to be printed since publishLast() is used.

from the docs

> Similar to publish, but it waits until the source observable completes
> and stores the last emitted value. Similarly to publishReplay and
> publishBehavior, this keeps storing the last value even if it has no
> more subscribers. If subsequent subscriptions happen, they will
> immediately get that last stored value and complete.

But this doesn't seem to happen here.

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/publishLast

Comment: I will only publish the last value once the Observable completes (ie. you call `subject.complete()`.

Comment: As Will noted, there is no last value. Consider using `shareReplay(1)` instead? That doesn't want for your source stream to complete.